# Image Picker does not crop the image for me correctly (swift) (firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an image picker and after the image got picked, it should get uploaded into my Firebase Storage. 
Now I have one problem: Somehow all the images dont get cropped correctly.

Did I misplace some Code, because that's the only thing I could think of, since I already got 
`picker.allowsEditing = true`

The picture gets uploaded correctly, but not how I intended to crop it. The "cropper-window" shows up, but it doesnt get saved as intended.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class editViewController: UIViewController  {

    @IBOutlet var pfp: UIImageView!

    var fireImage: UIImage? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupPfp()
    }

    func setupPfp(){
        pfp.layer.cornerRadius = pfp.frame.height/2
        pfp.clipsToBounds = true
        pfp.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(presentPicker))
        pfp.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func presentPicker(){
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = self
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func uploadToFirebase(){

        guard let imageSelected = self.fireImage else {
            print("Image is nil")
            return
        }

        guard let imageData = imageSelected.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else {
            return
        }

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://lidjd-9dad5.appspot.com")
        let storageProfileRef = storageRef.child("profileImages").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let docRef = db.collection("users").document(userID)
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        storageProfileRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { (storageMetaData, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            storageProfileRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                if let metaImageUrl = url?.absoluteString{
                    print(metaImageUrl)
                    docRef.updateData([
                        "profileimage": metaImageUrl
                    ]){ err in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        print("Profile Image successfully updated")
                        }}
                }
            }
        }


    }

}

extension editViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let imageSelected = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            fireImage = imageSelected
            pfp.image = imageSelected
        }

        if let imageOriginal = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            fireImage = imageOriginal
            pfp.image = imageOriginal
        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        uploadToFirebase()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose one of them .. in your current code you are always using orignal image

```
  extension editViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let imageSelected = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
                fireImage = imageSelected
                pfp.image = imageSelected
            }

            else if let imageOriginal = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                fireImage = imageOriginal
                pfp.image = imageOriginal
            }

            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            uploadToFirebase()

        }

    }
```